# How to invert an array?

Tags: perl

In this script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my @ar = (1,2,10,3,5);

@ar = sort {$a <=> $b} @ar;
```

does `@ar` now contain `(1,2,3,5,10)`.

Now would I like to get the inverse array i.e. `(4,6,7,8,9)`.

Any suggestions how that can be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When working with set operations, hashes work well:

```
my %have = map {$_ => 1} @ar;

my @inv  = grep {not $have{$_}} 1 .. 10;

print "@inv\n"; # 4 6 7 8 9
```

If you will not know the bounds before hand, and would like to determine them from the min/max of `@ar`, since its sorted that becomes easy:

```
my @inv = grep {not $have{$_}} $ar[0] .. $ar[-1];
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a good application for smart matching:

```
  @inverse = grep { ! ($_ ~~ @ar) } 1..10;
```

Selects all values between 1 and 10 that are not in `@ar`.

Comment: This is ok as long as `@ar` isn't too big.  Smart matching has to use sequential search when matching against an array.

Comment: +1 Because, well, I like it. But as cjm has pointed out, it's `O(n*k)` where `n` represents the number of items in the input (`@ar`) and `k` the total length to invert (`1..10`).

Answer (score 4):

[Acme::Tools](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Acme%3a%3aTools)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Acme::Tools qw(minus);

my @ar = (1,2,10,3,5);
@ar = sort {$a <=> $b} @ar; 
my @all = 1..10;
my @inv = minus( \@all, \@ar );
print "@ar\n";
print "@inv\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the array is sorted, there's only 1 value you need to be comparing against at any given time, so you could do this:

```
my @ar = (1,2,10,3,5);

@ar = sort {$a <=> $b} @ar;

my @inverse = do {
  my $i = 0;
  grep { $_ != $ar[$i] or (++$i, 0) } 1 .. $ar[-1]
};
```

As written here, you don't need a check for `$i` going off the end of the array, because the range ends at `$ar[-1]`.  If you change that condition, then you would need to check for `$i > $#ar`, or just push N+1 onto `@ar` before computing the inverse and pop it off afterward (where N is the maximum value of the range).  This code also assumes there won't be any duplicate values in the array.

I decided to benchmark the leading candidates, using 5,000 numbers between 1-10,000:

```
use 5.010;
use Benchmark 'cmpthese';

my (@orig, %used);
while (@orig < 5000) {
  my $rand = 1 + int rand 10000;
  push @orig, $rand unless $used{$rand}++;
}

my @ar = sort {$a <=> $b} @orig;

cmpthese(-3, {
  sorted => sub {
    push @ar, 10001;
    my @inverse = do {
      my $i = 0;
      grep { $_ != $ar[$i] or (++$i, 0) } 1 .. 10000
    };
    pop @ar;
  },

  unsorted => sub {
    @ar = sort {$a <=> $b} @orig;

    push @ar, 10001;
    my @inverse = do {
      my $i = 0;
      grep { $_ != $ar[$i] or (++$i, 0) } 1 .. 10000
    };
    pop @ar;
  },

  hash => sub {
    my %have = map {$_ => 1} @ar;

    my @inverse = grep {not $have{$_}} 1 .. 10000;
  },

  smartmatch => sub {
    my @inverse = grep { ! ($_ ~~ @ar) } 1 .. 10000;
  },
});
```

On Perl 5.10.1, I got:

```
              Rate smartmatch       hash   unsorted     sorted
smartmatch 0.708/s         --      -100%      -100%      -100%
hash         180/s     25279%         --        -7%       -67%
unsorted     193/s     27183%         8%         --       -65%
sorted       551/s     77745%       207%       185%         --
```

As you can see, repeatedly smart matching against an array is *slow*.  My approach is roughly the same speed as the hash-based approach, if you include the time it takes to sort `@ar`.  If you discount that (perhaps you have to sort `@ar` anyway for other reasons), then my approach is about twice as fast as the hash.

Comment: Not as idiomatic, but very inventive! +1

Answer (score 0):

My Perl is a little rusty but here's the basic idea.

```
# Put the contents of `@ar` into the keys 
# of a temporary hash variable (to make lookups easy)
my %temp_hash = %{{ map { $_ => 1 } @ar }};

# Then use a `for` loop starting at the first value
# in `@ar` and ending at the last value:
for (my $i = $ar[0]; $i <= $ar[$#ar-1]; $i++) {
    # For each value of your loop counter,
    # check whether that value exists as a key 
    # in your temporary hash variable. 
    # If it doesn't, push it on to your inverse array:
    push @inverse_array, $i if (not exists $temp_hash{$i});
}
```

Job done!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Set::IntSpan.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Set::IntSpan;

my @ar = (1,2,10,3,5); 
@ar = sort {$a <=> $b} @ar;

# min - max of given set
my $range = Set::IntSpan->new( "$ar[0]-$ar[-1]" );
# members of set
my $used  = Set::IntSpan->new( @ar );

# Calculates the missing numbers
my $unused = $range->diff( $used );

print join " ", $unused->elements;
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply

```
@inv = sort {$b <=> $a} @ar;
```

If you want to invert a random non-sorted array:

```
my @inv;
while(scalar @ar){
    push @inv pop @ar;
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong kind of "invert".  And if you did want to reverse the array like this, you should use the [reverse](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) function.